# flask and sqlite update values that might be empty

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, sql-update

I need to update values of a row in my database based on the post request that I receive from a form.

**The HTML form will send through the post request some or all the values that will be needed to update a row.** and I thought that I should be using *UPDATE* query to update the values in the row, but the values might be empty which throw a syntax error.

the HTML is:

```
<form action="/change-profile-information" method="POST">
  <label>email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" value={{result[0]}}>
  <label>name contact person</label>
  <input type="text" name="contact_person" value={{result[1]}}>
  <label>phone</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone" value={{result[2]}}>
  <label>address</label>
  <input type="text" name="address" value={{result[3]}}>
  <label>profile image</label>
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

while in my Flask function for the post request I am doing my SQLite query to update the values.

```
@app.route('/change-profile-information', methods=['POST'])
def change_profile_information():
    if 'username' in session:
        user_id = session['user_id']

        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.form.get('last_name')
        phone = request.form.get('phone')
        address = request.form.get('address')
        image = request.form.get('image')
        # change in DB
        con = lite.connect('base.db') 
        cur = con.cursor()
        try:
            cur.execute(f"""UPDATE farmers 
                            SET email='{email}', name='{first_name}'
                            lastname='{last_name}',
                            phone='{phone}', address='{address}',
                            profile_image='{image}' 
                            WHERE farmer_id='{user_id}';""")
            # reload page
            return redirect('/settings-farmer.html', code=302)                
        except lite.Error as error:
            return "Failed: "+str(error)
        finally:
            if (con):
                con.close()
```

In this last piece of code the values of `first_name = request.form.get('first_name')` might be empty and this gives me a problem. In fact if I send the request with the parameter of `last_name` it will through an error saying `Failed: near "lastname": syntax error`. It seems that if the parameter are empty I still have empty strings, but that would still throw a syntax error for SQLite.

Should I be using `?` and `VALUES('{last_name}')` or maybe I should be using `REPLACE` instead of `UPDATE`?

Comment: if you want you can bind the user to fill the complete form using required in input tag. And you don't have last_name in your input field in the code you have showed. If you don't want set default value for the field which could be empty when you create the table. I don't know sqlite module, I use flask-sqlalchemy module and I think it is better than sqlite because it support many databases.

Comment: We have found two syntax problem in the code: it is missing a `,` after `name='{first_name}'`, and for a Flask stand point the redirect should be `return redirect('/settings-farmer', code=302)` without the `.html`. We still get the problem that is not updating the table.

Comment: have you checked whether there is any record with that user_id because it will only update where the farmer_id matches user_id and in place of lite.error use `except Exception as e` it will also print any other error also if it is happening

Comment: Thank you so much, we have solved it. After the `cur.execute()` I would need to also `con.commit()`.

Comment: good, you solved.